# Is there a way in Swift to create a function that takes a Value.Protocol and returns a Value.Type?

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, service-locator

I'm trying to create a Dependency Container, similar to [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject), but I want to return the metatype '.Type' instead of a concrete type. 
Is it even possible?

I've tried creating a basic concept to see if it would work.

```swift
class DependencyContainer {
    var types: [ObjectIdentifier: Any] = [:]

    func register<Product>(_ concreteType: Any.Type, to protoType: Product.Type) {
        self.types[ObjectIdentifier(protoType)] = concreteType
    }

    func get<Product>(of type: Product.Type) -> Product.Type? {
        return self.types[ObjectIdentifier(type)] as? Product.Type
    }
}

protocol TestProduct {
    var number: Int { get }
    init(number: Int)
}

struct SomeTestProduct: TestProduct {
    var number: Int
}

let container = DependencyContainer()
container.register(SomeTestProduct.self, to: TestProduct.self)
let testProduct = container.get(of: TestProduct.self)
```

I expected the get function to return a `SomeTestProduct.Type` as a `TestProduct.Type`, but instead it always returns `nil` because the compiler thinks I want a `TestProduct.Protocol` and fails the type cast.

Comment: IDK the answer to your question, but FYI, this is the Service Locator pattern, not Dependancy Injection

Comment: Oh you're right, never heard of that term before, thanks! If anybody wants to know the difference between the two I found a post by Martin Fowler about it https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection